# How to serve synchronous client server communication with asynchronous Inter-service communication?

Tags: asynchronous, microservices

We have a service which communicates with another service using asynchronous communication(message queue) but still the client server communication happens through REST. Now we have a requirement that when user perform a persists call on service A it should trigger some modification on service B. Client should get success response only if both services successful completed their respective tasks. Reason for that is we need to make sure that user should not able to perform next step on partially completed data. We are not interested in concurrent users due to nature of the domain. We have very limited capability on replacing REST client server implementation with a protocol such as web socket, AMQP

What are the ways to achieve this type of a scenario with asynchronous interservice communication? Is there any reputed pattern/style of programming for implementing this type of requirement? Any framework or lib on Java?

Or is it a bad idea to rely on asynchronous communication to achieve blocking business requirement?

Comment: So what i understand you got 2 services communicating async and your client is interacting with one of the service synchronously. Now you want your client to get response only when both services are done ? If yes then you have to rely on queue to notify your calling service once other service finished work . your client will keep on pinging the status until the call is completed. it's not unusual pattern and is common in Micro services communication.

Comment: @Imran Yes that is our requirement.

Comment: We thought of client side pooling but ignored thinking that there would be more modern and efficient solutions.

Comment: for client web sockets is other option instead polling but async part will remain the same.